# Changing bar width with pointPadding in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I`m trying to increase the bar height in the following chart:

[image: Actual chart]

The bars are placed in overlaping using `pointPadding` and `pointPlacement`.
When I add `pointWidth`, those options are ignored.

Is there a workaround to this?

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#chart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            spacingBottom: 10,
            spacingTop: 20,
            spacingLeft: 15,
            spacingRight: 15
        },
        title: {
            text: 'F',
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['F']
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'M',
            color: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.70)',
            borderColor: '#999999',
            borderRadius: 0,
            data: [4380000.00],
            pointPadding: 0,
            pointPlacement: 0.2
        }, {
            name: 'P',
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.70)',
            borderColor: '#000',
            borderRadius: 0,
            data: [4000000],
            pointPadding: 0.1,
            pointPlacement: 0
        }, {
            name: 'F',
            color: 'rgba(140,255,160,0.90)',
            borderColor: '#339938',
            borderRadius: 0,
            data: [3226923.00],
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }]
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no property columnWidth for a bar series, however, there is a property [**pointWidth**](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.pointWidth) which you can use.

Comment: My mistake, I was already using pointWidth.
But when I use it, the option pointPadding stop working...

Comment: Are you trying to get something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xdoz4evp/

Comment: Exactly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about pointPadding and manipulate with pointWidth.

```
series: [{
  name: 'M',
  color: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.70)',
  borderColor: '#999999',
  borderRadius: 0,
  data: [4380000.00],
  //pointPadding: 0,
  pointPlacement: -0.2,
  pointWidth: 120
}, {
  name: 'P',
  color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.70)',
  borderColor: '#000',
  borderRadius: 0,
  data: [4000000],
  //pointPadding: 0.1,
  pointPlacement: 0,
  pointWidth: 80
}, {
  name: 'F',
  color: 'rgba(140,255,160,0.90)',
  borderColor: '#339938',
  borderRadius: 0,
  data: [3226923.00],
  //pointPadding: 0.2,
  pointPlacement: 0.2,
  pointWidth: 50
}]
```

You can see the result here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qv8n7y02/1/)